# VBA form control to create input values

Tags: excel, vba

I am a warehouse lead that is trying to set up a better system for keeping track of the tractor trailers I have coming in and out of the facility every day.

The way I have this spreadsheet set up currently is Column `A` is the Tractor Trailer numbers.
Then columns `B:D` are the different location they come from.
I have `countif` statements at the bottom of all the `B:D` columns to count for the value `X`.
I have a hidden column in `F` that has the following `countif` statement: `=COUNTIF(B3:D3,"X")`
and then in column E I have the following if statement:
`=IF(F3=1,"","X")`.

Is there any way I could use VBA to make a form control automatically get an X value put into rows `B:D` based on matching the information in Column A with the correct facilities the tractor trailers are coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the VBA accomplish this.  Excel worksheet functions are made for this.  If you could post a screen shot I'll try and help you out. 
The two biggest problems I see is that you are calculating a lot of blank cells.  Also try and avoid overlapping formulas.

You would make your life a whole hell of a lot easier if you'd watch 4 or 5 videos on Excel a week.  [ExcelIsFun](https://www.youtube.com/user/ExcelIsFun) is a great free resource.  His video are 5mins to about 20 minutes.  In a month your co-workers will be asking you for help.

Comment: I have the project working.  I was just looking to make it work in a different way.